# Clicking checkbox on web page using Applescript

Tags: checkbox, applescript

I'm somewhat new to Applescript, and I am trying to make Applescript check a checkbox to select it. I want the checkbox to be clicked regardless of whether or not it's already checked. Here is the checkbox's location according to the Accessibility Inspector:

```
<AXApplication: “Safari”>
<AXWindow: “Studio”>
<AXGroup>
<AXGroup>
<AXGroup>
 <AXScrollArea: “”>
  <AXWebArea: “”>
   <AXGroup: “”>
    <AXCheckBox: “”>

Attributes:
AXRole:  “AXCheckBox”
AXSubrole:  “(null)”
AXRoleDescription:  “check box”
AXChildren:  “<array of size 0>”
AXHelp:  “”
AXParent:  “<AXGroup: “”>”
AXPosition:  “x=1104 y=825”
AXSize:  “w=18 h=19”
AXTitle:  “”
AXDescription:  “”
AXValue:  “0”
AXFocused (W):  “0”
AXEnabled:  “1”
AXWindow:  “<AXWindow: “Studio”>”
AXSelectedTextMarkerRange (W):  “<AXTextMarkerRange 0x101937860 [0x7fff76e43fa0]>{startMarker:<AXTextMarker 0x1019378b0 [0x7fff76e43fa0]>{length = 24, bytes = 0xac01000000000000c0366e23010000001700000001000000} endMarker:<AXTextMarker 0x101938030 [0x7fff76e43fa0]>{length = 24, bytes = 0xac01000000000000c0366e23010000001700000001000000}}”
AXStartTextMarker:  “<AXTextMarker 0x101938030 [0x7fff76e43fa0]>{length = 24, bytes = 0xa00000000000000098975e0d010000000000000001000000}”
AXEndTextMarker:  “<AXTextMarker 0x1019378b0 [0x7fff76e43fa0]>{length = 24, bytes = 0xa200000000000000405e7812010000000000000001000000}”
AXVisited:  “0”
AXLinkedUIElements:  “(null)”
AXSelected:  “0”
AXBlockQuoteLevel:  “0”
AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXWindow: “Studio”>”
AXTitleUIElement:  “(null)”
AXAccessKey:  “(null)”
AXRequired:  “0”
AXInvalid:  “false”
AXARIABusy:  “0”

Actions:
AXPress - press
AXShowMenu - show menu
```

I've tried multiple methods to get this to work, and I haven't been able to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a link to the page and describe the button.

Comment: I cannot post a link, this page is a privileged page with settings to systems that should not be openly accessible to the general public.

Answer (score 0):

Your question with the Accessibility Inspector info is not very helpful I am afraid.

It would help if we could see the actual elements of the web page,

Have a look at [this page](http://sislands.com/coin70/week4/chkBoxTest.htm) which I found that shows check boxes and the code that makes it up.

Each element has a name and maybe within some other element.

on the page I can use this Applescript/Javascript to check the **check1** checkbox.

Hopefully this will give you an idea of how to go about it.

But remember this code snippet is tailored to this page.

Open the web page and run this applescript

```
tell application "Safari"

set doc to document 1


    do JavaScript "document.forms['testform']['check1'].checked = true" in doc
end tell
```

---

**Update:** Applescript GUI

---

**Update:2** take into account "clicked regardless of whether or not it's already checked"

---

Taking a punt with your Accessibility Inspector. Which is a bit useless (not your fault)

try:

```
   activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events"
    set theCheckbox to (checkbox 1 of group 3 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1 of application process "Safari")

    set isEnabled to value of theCheckbox as boolean
    if not isEnabled then
        click theCheckbox   
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I can't do this, I need to use purely Applescript, no javascript

Comment: Can I ask why? also it is the applescript running the javascript

Comment: I don't know javascript, so I wouldn't know how to edit it to fit my needs, that and I don't like javascript.

Comment: If you don't know how to write it I not sure why you would not like it?. Most webpages use some javascript ( not to be confused with Java applets ) The two details needed are the form name and the check box name. You can either look for them and try and use them or you can post the check boxes source html by viewing the page source and coping they check boxes html form <form> to </form> . Which should hold the details needed and not give away any trade secrets. And I can give them to you. If not then you maybe out of luck.

Comment: I've heard horror stories about javascript. The only reason it's still used is because everyone uses it and there is no other alternative. It's old and ugly. The form name is "frm2" and the check box has some javascript it, I don't know if that would do something bad to your method.. the checkbox name is "live_on" and its checked property is blank: "checked=""". The javascript  is this: onclick="document.getElementById('live_off').checked='';document.getElementById('live_on').checked='true';blocking('live_time','block');"

Comment: I have heard horror stories about the internet. The only reason it's still used is because everyone uses it and there is no other alternative. Actually there are alternatives. But they may or may not do the job a as well. Such is the case of clicking you checkbox. But we will never know unless you give more information. As I said in my answer the info you gave in your question is not helpful.

Comment: Applescript editor returns: "System Events got an error: Can’t get checkbox 1 of group 3 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of window 1 of application process "Safari". Invalid index."

Comment: By the way, the internet (the GUI of the internet that is) is slowly dying at the hands of mobile apps that pass data through the internet automatically.. that's my opinion anyway. Ex: no-one goes to youtube.com when on their phone, they instead use the youtube app.